# App not getting target url when opened through deep linking

Tags: ios, facebook, sdk, deep-linking

I have an iOS app that is opened via deep linking from the Facebook app when the user clicks on a story. The story has a link to a file. However when my app delegate's `application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:` is called, the url is simply 
`fb<appid>://authorize/` and does not contain the actual target link.

Does anybody know what's going on here?

According to (deprecated) https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/app-links, we have to add the link's subdomain as a "website" platform, and I did that to see if it solves the problem, but it didn't.

I just don't see the point of the Facebook app opening my app via deep linking without giving it the required contextual information.

Comment: Hi.. @wingman123 I am getting same issue.. Will you please help by sharing your solution for it..